# How to fix error 'Component: [x] subscribes from non-existent component [y]' in Apache Storm Trident topology

Tags: apache-storm, trident

I just implemented a trident DRPC function to process incoming messages and I am trying to persist the count of processed tuples at the final stage of the topology as a Trident state. Here is my topology:

```
topology.newDRPCStream("portfolio")
    .map(parseMapFunction,
        new Fields("portfolioUrn", "portfolioSourceSystem", "portfolioRegion",
            "portfolioTimestamp", "portfolioPayload"))
    .filter(new FilterNull())
    .flatMap(splitMapFunction,
        new Fields("portfolioUrn", "portfolioSourceSystem", "portfolioRegion",
            "portfolioTimestamp", "strategyCode"))
    .parallelismHint(1)
    .shuffle()
    .each(new Fields("strategyCode"), findMongoTradesFunction,
        new Fields("uitid", "id", "sourceSystem", "sourceTransactionTime", "publicationTime",
            "tradeVersion", "urn", "riskViewFrom", "riskViewTo", "authorized"))
    .parallelismHint(10)
    .shuffle()
    .filter(tradeFilterFunction)
    .parallelismHint(150)
    .groupBy(new Fields("uitid"))
    .aggregate(
        new Fields("portfolioUrn", "portfolioTimestamp", "strategyCode", "id", "sourceSystem",
            "sourceTransactionTime", "publicationTime", "tradeVersion", "urn", "riskViewFrom",
            "riskViewTo", "uitid"), reduceAggregateFunction,
        new Fields("portfolioUrn", "portfolioTimestamp", "strategyCode", "id", "sourceSystem",
            "sourceTransactionTime", "publicationTime", "tradeVersion", "urn", "riskViewFrom",
            "riskViewTo"))
    .parallelismHint(200)
    .groupBy(new Fields("portfolioUrn"))
    .persistentAggregate(stateFactory, new Count(), new Fields("count"));
```

While I am trying to submit this topology to Storm I am having this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [b-4] subscribes from non-existent component [$mastercoord-bg0])
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:273)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:387)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:159)
at com.citi.tm.portfolio.tps.PortfolioLauncher.main(PortfolioLauncher.java:34)
Caused by: InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [b-4] subscribes from non-existent component [$mastercoord-bg0])
at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$submitTopology_result$submitTopology_resultStandardScheme.read(Nimbus.java:8070)
at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$submitTopology_result$submitTopology_resultStandardScheme.read(Nimbus.java:8047)
at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$submitTopology_result.read(Nimbus.java:7981)
at org.apache.storm.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:86)
at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_submitTopology(Nimbus.java:306)
at org.apache.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.submitTopology(Nimbus.java:290)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyInDistributeMode(StormSubmitter.java:326)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:260)
... 3 more
```

I can successfully submit the topology if I remove the last 2 functions from that topology , that are:

```
.groupBy(new Fields("portfolioUrn"))
.persistentAggregate(stateFactory, new Count(), new Fields("count"));
```

After I run my aggregation function (aggregate()) I'd like to group tuples with 'portfolioUrn' field and persist the count into mongoDB. I don't understand why the last groupBy().persistentAggregate() section causes this error. Could you please help to find the reason?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found [this](https://grokbase.com/t/gg/storm-user/133kf7bttz/help-with-invalidtopologyexception) page which seems a similar case to me. Nathan Marz is stating that DRPC topologies do not support partition persist (as of 2013) and I believe it is the same for my case as well. I think, (not fully verified) Storm 1.2.1 DRPC topologies might not support state persistence at all.